# Pass gridview data(one page) to another page's gridview control using winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two pages in my windows application. Both pages have a gridview control. I can pass textbox values into 2nd form but my problem is, I dont know how to pass whole gridview data into 2nd form.

Form1:

```
public partial class Billing : Form
    {

        DataTable dt;
        public Billing()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetDataTable();
            txtBillNo.Text = Convert.ToString(billno);
        }

        public void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int row = dgvBilling.RowCount;
            DataRow dr;
            if (dgvBilling.RowCount != 0)
            {
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["IName"] = txtIName.Text.Trim();
                dr["Icode"] = txtIcode.Text.Trim();
                dr["Quantity"] = txtQuantity.Text.Trim();
                dr["UnitPrice"] = txtUnitPrice.Text.Trim();

                int amount = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text.Trim()) * Convert.ToInt32(txtUnitPrice.Text.Trim());
                dr["amount"] = Convert.ToString(amount);

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                int total = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < dgvBilling.Rows.Count; ++i)
                {
                    total += Convert.ToInt32(dgvBilling.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                    txtTotal.Text = "Rs/" + "" + Convert.ToString(total);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                //dt = SetDataTable();
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["IName"] = txtIName.Text.Trim();
                dr["Icode"] = txtIcode.Text.Trim();
                dr["Quantity"] = txtQuantity.Text.Trim();
                dr["UnitPrice"] = txtUnitPrice.Text.Trim();

                int amount = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text.Trim()) * Convert.ToInt32(txtUnitPrice.Text.Trim());
                dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToString(amount);

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                int total = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < dgvBilling.Rows.Count; ++i)
                {
                    total += Convert.ToInt32(dgvBilling.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                    txtTotal.Text = "Rs/" + "" + Convert.ToString(total);
                }
                RetrieveData();
            }
        }


        public DataTable SetDataTable()
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("IName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn("Icode", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn("UnitPrice", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkBoxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = "";
            checkBoxColumn.Width = 50;
            checkBoxColumn.Name = "checkBoxColumn";
            dgvBilling.Columns.Insert(0, checkBoxColumn);
            dgvBilling.DataSource = dt;
            return dt;
        }          

        private void btnPrintBill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                              
            PrintBill pb = new PrintBill();            
            pb.Controls["lblNetAmount"].Text = txtTotal.Text;
            pb.Show();

        }
    }
}
```

form2:

```
public partial class PrintBill : Form
{
    public PrintBill()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        Billing bg = new Billing();                   
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bg.RetrieveData();

    }   
}
```

When I click PrintBill button I want to show 2nd form with the gridview values of first form...

Comment: you can use session state to pass the datatable which is your gridview datasource as it seems.
`Session["griddata"] = myDataTable` in the first form and `DataTable myDataTable = (DataTable)Session["griddata"];` in the 2nd page then bind it to the gridview

Comment: i am using windows forms, so there is no session state....

Comment: What's the data source of your first form grid?

Comment: @Reza Aghaei i dont use any datasource for this(value passing grid)...

Comment: as i said i am new to c#, now i am searching in google how to pass datatable dt(which is in my btnEnter_click) to the method which is shown in below. i just try this but it only returns header values not rows. i am calling header values by a method setdatatable(). i think dt returns this methods not the rows. how solve it bro? so far i tried this                     public DataTable RetrieveData()
        {
            DataTable dtr;
            dtr = (DataTable)dt;
            return dtr;
        }  and call this method in 2nd page.

Comment: @Rajaaar Do you have a method to load data? and what is the return type of that method?

Comment: @Rajaaar It's completely OK and I only guide you to use StackOwerflow better :)

Comment: i am updated my full codes of both pages. when i press the PrintBill button i want to show the gridview of first form in 2nd form gridview. it just shows headers and empty rows.

Comment: @Rajaaar It's obviously is because you are passing an empty data table to that form.  You should fill your data table. I'll post an answer for you.

Comment: @Rajaaar You can check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a good option you can use a `DataTable` as data source of your `DataGridView` and when you need to pass data to other form, use `Copy` method of that `DataTable`. Here is an example:

Your GridForm:

```
public partial class GridForm : Form
{
    public GridForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //we will this as data source
    private DataTable table;

    private void GridForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create the data table here and bind it to grid
        table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IName", typeof(string)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Icode", typeof(string)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(string)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UnitPrice", typeof(string)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(string)));

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }

    private void passDataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //When you need to pass data, use Copy method of data table
        var clone = table.Copy();

        //Pass data to other form
        var f = new OtherForm(clone);
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Your OtherForm:

```
public partial class OtherForm : Form
{
    DataTable table;
    public OtherForm(DataTable value)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //get passed data and put it in some member variable for next usages
        table = value;

        //Bind data to other grid or do other things here or in Form Load event
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }
}
```

Comment: working fine both sample form as well as real project. Thanks bro for coding as well as make me to understand stack overflow.thanks again.

Comment: By the way, since you have reached 15 reputation now, you can vote up for as many answer you find useful, including accepted one by click on up arrow :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can make that datarow/DataTable a global variable to make it accessible to other class. And also, you can create a public method that returns a datatable like :

```
public DataTable RetrieveData()
{
     DataTable dt;
//retrive necessary data here
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: please provide an example code for passing gridview or datatable value from one page to another.... because i am new to c#.